# Clojure interop with Java: how to call a class?

Tags: java, maven, clojure, interop, leiningen

I have a Java app that has a class at this address, inside a standard Maven layout:

```
src/main/java/com/ollio/nlp/Transformer.java
```

The class and method that I want looks like this:

```
package com.ollio.nlp;

public class Transformer {
    public String transform(String JSONInput) {
```

I store the jar artifact locally in my Clojure app at this address:

```
maven_repository/local/nlp/1.0-SNAPSHOT/nlp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I have tried a dozen variations to import it into my Clojure app, such as:

```
 (:import
    [com.ollio.nlp.Transformer])
```

But I keep getting the error "No such namespace".

What is the correct way to import this?

EDITED:

Here is how I currently try to do the import statement:

```
(ns slick.query
  (:import
    [nlp.*])
```

I also tried:

```
(ns slick.query
  (:import
    [com.ollio.nlp.*])
```

I tried a few other variations.

The project.clj file looks like this:

```
(defproject slick "0.1"
  :description "slick is  an API for other ollio services, such as our mobile app."
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
             [com.taoensso/timbre "3.2.1"]
             [dire "0.5.1"]
             [slingshot "0.10.3"]
             [ring "1.4.0-RC1"]
             [clj-time "0.6.0"]
             [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.5"]
             [compojure "1.3.4"]
             [com.novemberain/monger "2.0.1"]
             [org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.4"]
             [manifold "0.1.0"]
             [me.raynes/fs "1.4.4"]
             [org.clojure/core.incubator "0.1.3"]
             [clj-stacktrace "0.2.7"]
             [overtone/at-at "1.2.0"]
             [ring/ring-json "0.3.1"]
             [clj-http "1.1.2"]
             [org.clojure/core.cache "0.6.4"]
             [cheshire "5.5.0"]
             [org.clojure/core.match "0.3.0-alpha4"]
             [local/nlp "1.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  :repositories {"local" ~(str (.toURI (java.io.File. "maven_repository")))}
  :disable-implicit-clean true
  :source-paths      ["src/clojure"]
  :java-source-paths ["src/java"]
  :main slick.core
  :aot :all
  :jvm-opts ["-Xms100m" "-Xmx1000m" "-XX:-UseCompressedOops"])
```

Comment: are you using `:import` inside the `ns` form? because if you were accidentally using `:import` outside of `ns`, you would get that error. The best thing to do is use `(ns .... (:import ...))` but `(import ...)` works at the top level (usually useful for the repl).

Comment: Also, how are you adding the maven dep to your classpath? Are you using maven to run Clojure? Using leiningen? Using boot?

Comment: How is your project set up?  Where is the java source tree relative to the clojure source tree?

Comment: Alan, the Java project is entirely separate. It is kept in a standard default Maven directory structure. I copied over the jar artifact, using the command that you see above.

Comment: There's still not enough information to diagnose the problem.  What's the full error that contains "No such namespace"?  Is that really the error message? (I'm trying to generate exactly that error message with by creating problems in one of my projects, and haven't succeeded so far.)  When does it occur?  Is there a line number?  What's happening in your source code there?  Can you make the error happen using `lein compile`?  Can you make it happen using `require` at the REPL?  `require`ing what?  It may have nothing to do with the Java lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to change the last period in your `:import` statement into a space:

```
(ns mynamespace
  (:import [com.ollio.nlp Transformer]))
```

(EDIT: You can't use wildcards here.  Every class that in `com.ollio.nlp` must be listed explicitly, separated by spaces.)  That will allow you to use `Transformer` unqualified:

```
(.transform (Transformer. <add constructor args here>) my-json-input)
```

As @noisesmith said, the `:import` statement should be part of an `ns` declaration.

There's also a good chance that there are problems with the way that the project is set up.  You've given no indication that that is likely, but it often happens when one is starting to use Java interop, I believe.  (It happened to me, in any event.)  So @AlanThompson's advice may be relevant.

You an also simply remove the `:import` statement, and use the Java class name in fully qualified form, e.g.:

```
(.transform (com.ollio.nlp.Transformer. <add constructor args here>) my-json-input)
```

If you get an error when you do that, then there's probably a problem with the setup (unless you're using the class incorrectly).

(I'm not sure how helpful any of this.  Alan Thompson's answer is probably the appropriate one.)

Comment: I do not want to mix java source code and clojure source code in one project, so Alan Thompson's answer is a bit misdirected. I've got a jar artifact I'm trying to include in my project.

Comment: Given what you wrote originally, it was a reasonable guess.  Some of the same issues come up whether you include source or not.  See my latest edit about wildcards.

Comment: This works: "(.transform (com.ollio.nlp.Transformer. <add constructor args here>) my-json-input)"

Comment: Great!  In that case, explicitly listing classes separated by spaces after `com.olllio.nlp` in the import statement should allow you to use `Transformer.` without the rest of its name, but that's your choice.  There's something to be said for making the source of the class completely explict at the point at which it's used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are mixing java and clojure source code in one project, you should first review the lein docs:  https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/MIXED_PROJECTS.md

Also, if you posted your project.clj and the layout of your java/clojure sources, it would be easier to spot what is missing.

Comment: I do not want to mix java and clojure source code in one project.